# Как вырезать из имени последнего лога субстринг и использовать это как параметр в программе?

Tags: строки, bat

ОC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit

Есть определенный bat файл который копирует ежедневно фалы и создает логи в определенной папке. Формат имени лога "SBL_YYYYMMDD_hhmmss". Где YYYY год, MM месяц и т.д...

Кроме этих логовов в будущем могут появиться другие, но они не будуь начинаться на "SBL_". Иногда файл по пока неизвестной мне причине не испольняеться по несколько дней.

**Желаемый результат**: Я хочу вырезать из последнего лога строку в формате YYYYMMDD. Дальнейший процесс я уже прописал. Мне нужно только вырезать строку из имени последнего файла начниаешегося с "SBL_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справился сам:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR %path% /B /O:-D') DO set lastSblLog=%%I & IF "!lastSblLog:~0,3!"=="SBL" (goto :next_step)

:next_step
делай что-то
```